# Polymer databinding confusion with Object Properties

Tags: polymer

EDIT - THIS IS A COMPLETE RED HERRING.  One of the `user` properties down the hierarchy had the `readOnly` property set for user.  This was preventing it propagating.

I am struggling to understand databinding and how values propagate when the property changes I have a tree structured set of elements (the structure is spread across separate element definitions - **not** with `<content>` tags as possibly implied by the structure show below)

```
<my-app user="{{user}}">
  <my-session user="{{user}}">
    <my-login user="{{user}}"></my-login>
  </my-session>
  <template is="dom-if" if="[[user.name]]">
    <my-pages user="{{user}}">
      <iron-pages>
        <my-menu user="{{user}}"></my-menu>
        <my-reports user="{{user}}"></my-reports>
      </iron-pages>
    </my-pages>
  </template>
</my-app>
```

Each of these elements at their different definitions define a property

```
user : {
  type: Object,
  notify: true
}
```

And all the elements are linked with two way data binding

`<my-pages>` is lazy loaded using `importHref` after the user has logged on (and therefore `user.name` is defined)

I have a property of `user` called `keys` which is used for access control.  In particular both `<my-menu>` and a sub element of `<my-reports>` uses this to determine which menu items to display.

This all works fine on initial log on. But if I change the logged on user, then this change to the user property is apparently not propagating properly

What I can see is that from the debugger triggered during a page change from iron pagess I can see that the `<my-app>` 's `user` has the new logged on user value BUT `<my-pages>`'s `user` has the old user.  For some reason data binding of `user` is not working down the tree structure, even though it appears to have successfully propagated up from `<my-login>` to `<my-app>`.  .

I am assuming that possibly the "object" of `user` is not changing only the paths.  I am getting confused about what I should be doing here.  Can someone help.

Comment: There's a syntax error in your code. You have not closed `my-pages` element.

Comment: I found the bug by adding an observer on user property down the hierarchy and in doing so discovered one with the readOnly property set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really cannot tell what's wrong with your code with the information that you have provided except for the `syntax error` where instead of closing `my-pages` you have started a new one, but here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jtb9mTp6Mzdlz8IlCyqy) emulating your code. I was able to successfully change the user for all the elements.

Comment: The real code doesn't have the problem you mention, but I discovered an intermediate element with a readOnly: true in its property definition of `user`, which was stopping the change propagating